# How to debug Django with allauth package error

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am struggling with an error all day long.

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku. Everything works perfectly offline with the social authentication.

When I deploy the application I receive an error:

[image]

I have tried settings the SITE_ID but nothing changes.

Also I have checked that my DB have the Site objects created.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info and the exact wording of your error message, also your programs, what is your configuration, SocialApp models and the link with Allauth, models, views, URL, etc.  My impression if it works fine in test mode on your computer but not in deployment in a cloud, for example; It could be related to the data access or authorization... but with this limited info, difficult to know.

Comment: Hey there @guy-mercier ! I updated my initial post. Moreover, I have Django 2 and I just implemented the social auth from [this post](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/) .